# How can i convert Json request to base 64 in JMeter Preprocessor

Tags: jmeter, base64, preprocessor

I have a following Json

Ex :
var Jsonfile = [
{
"value": "3",
"type" : "string",
"label: "Repaymentday"
},

{
"value": "3",
"type" : "string",
"label: "Repaymentday"
},
];

i need to store all this requests in a single variable and i need to convert those values as Base64. i am adding all this request in Preprocessor and i need to pass this variable into JMeter request(as base64 value).
Could someone please how to achieve this in JMeter

Comment: Could you please format the JSON and correct the syntax? This online tool could be useful (JSON Formatter)[https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) available in [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)) which can perform the encoding of arbitrary text (or JMeter Variable)

   ```
   ${__base64Encode(foo,)}
   ```
2. If you don't want or cannot use JMeter Plugins you can do the same using JMeter's built-in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy('foo'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)}
   ```

Replace `foo` with the actual text you want to encode and that would be it

[image]

Comment: If foo is the variable - this should be used - ${__groovy(vars.get("foo").bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)} - handy for lazy developers who jump into Jmeter after seeign youtube shorts without going to documentation and then struggling like me!